# What is the correct Axios syntax to upload an image to my local server?

Tags: react-native, axios, postman

I am wanting to upload an image from my javascript/react-native code to a local server with axios. Here is my code currently for which I am getting a 404 request failed error (Note that when I run it in postman, it works fine so it is obviously an issue with my syntax):

```
 import axios from "axios";

export const uploadReceipt = async (expenseId, imageData) => {
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("receipt", imageData);

  axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/expenses/${expenseId}/receipts`, formData, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",

    }
  });
};
```

**Note** that imageData is the filepath, like so: `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.app.expenseapp/files/Pictures/JPEG_20190929_151217_613504889806204680.jpg`

**Here is my Postman generated code snippet:**

```
POST /expenses/5b996064dfd5b783915112f5/receipts HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.17.1
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 806897c2-ae58-4687-b4ca-99724d7981ce,26260c15-d96e-4162-bfb3-fd8a0b2576d2
Host: localhost:3000
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 7291
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache


Content-Disposition: form-data; name="receipt"; filename="/Users/user/Documents/bee.png


------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

**And the image version for just in case:**
[image]

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing mistakes in your `axios` syntax but, your `imageData` variable should contain `uri`, `name` and `type` properties.

Example :

```js
formData.append("receipt", {
    uri: imageUri, //uri of image
    name: imageName, //name of the image
    type: typeOfImage //type of the image like 'image/jpg' or  'image/png' 
});
```

Keep everything as it is.